# I have a problem when i migrate table . this problem is given below

Tags: php, laravel

This type of question is already asked in stackoverflow. There are some solutions but I have the same problem and I cannot fix it.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->integer('price');
        $table->string('image');
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

}
```

I'm receiving this error when trying to migrate:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
>   1005 Can't create table `project_rms`.`#sql-4448_15f` (errno: 150
>   "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table
>   `items` add constraint `items_category_id_foreign` foreign key
>   (`category_id`) references `categories` (`id`) on delete cascade)

Please help me find a solution, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your primary key is unsigned big integer, your foreign key needs to be unsigned big integer too.

Here is the working example of your code:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id'); //this line is changed
        $table->string('name');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->integer('price');
        $table->string('image');
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed
I think you find out your solution from here.[enter link description here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/laravel-relationship-foreign-key-delete?page=1)